# How do I hide or remove "X-ATG-Version" from the response header?

Tags: security, header, httpresponse, atg, jboss-4.2.x

I am working with the ATG platform and cannot figure out how to hide or remove the section of the response header "X-ATG-Version: xxxxxxx". I am using JBoss and I have figured out how to remove the "X-powered-by" part of the header but no luck with the ATG part. I am trying to accomplish this for security purposes.

Answer (score 5):

You are not saying which version of ATG you are running or whether you are hosting it behind a WebServer.

In the [ATG Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/apidoc/atg/servlet/pipeline/HeadPipelineServlet.html#isAddingAtgVersionHeader()) it suggests that you can turn off the header in the `HeadPipelineServlet` using the `addingAtgVersionHeader` property. You can find the `HeadPipelineServlet` in the `/atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/DynamoHandler` component. When you do add this property, make sure you add it via the properties file and restart. Changing it in `/dyn/admin` does not make a difference.

Alternatively you can hide it in your Webserver Configuration. In Apache the following is sufficient:

```
Header unset X-ATG-Version
```

And it works reliably.

Comment: Sorry, I am using ATG 9.1 and using JBoss application server. I am new to ATG and JBoss. I think the server configuration would be the way to go for me. However, I am not sure which .config or .xml file in JBoss to add the string you have listed above.

Comment: The `Header unset X-ATG-Version` configuration is in Apache in the httpd.conf. Your best bet would then be to change it in the DynamoHandler.properties in your localconfig.